# convert a commandline with newlines in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

On a Windows 7 commandline I use the `msg` command to send a message to a remote PC like this, which works fine:

```
msg * /servername:computer1 line1^
more?
more? line2
```

The circumflex (`^`) at the end of first line forces a newline, then I press "enter" two times. The result is a message box on remote PC with 2 lines.

How can get this command to work in VBScript like this:

```
set wshshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
intreturn = wshshell.run("cmd /c msg.exe " & _
                         "/server:computer1 * line1^" & _
                         vbcrlf & "line2")
```

Comment: FTR, `^` doesn't "force a newline". It *escapes* the next character.

Comment: you are right. i know that. i meant it that way, and my english is not the best. sorry and thanks for the comment to eliminate misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go the route via cmd or use stin as input.

```
Set wso = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wso.run "msg.exe * line1" & VbCrLf & "line2", , False
```

It would work like this

Comment: You may want to select this answer.